# How to create rounded shadow - Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, shadow

How to create shadow as in oval of picture to a linearlayout

I can create shadow using following script but it's thickness from left to write is same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
     <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
     <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
     <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
     <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
    <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I need shadow which is thick in center area but narrow in both sides left and right.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement

Comment: Question elaborated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a 9patch and use it, but in your case it might not be the best practise. So maybe you can try to use radial gradient, but it will be variable device to device... To have radial gradient you can try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="180"
                android:endColor="#00000000"
                android:gradientRadius="360"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:type="radial" />
        </shape>
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

**Edit:** Second thought, probably 9patch is best case for you...